# Error in mutate_(.data, .dots = compat_as_lazy_dots(...)) : argument ".data" is missing, with no default

Tags: r

I have data frame I wanted to run the following code. However I got the error. As far as I understand I need to use .data format data.

```
  mutate(file = "mix.data") %>% # add the name of our file
      mutate(filenumber = as.numeric(str_match(file, "\\d{4}"))) %>% # add the year
      mutate(topic = str_match(file, "(.*?)_")[2]) # add president
```

I am running the code in the following link, in case you would like to see.

https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/tutorial-sentiment-analysis-in-r/notebook

So could you let me know what is the needed code before running my code?

Thanks.

Comment: In that code you aren't feeding in a `data.frame` to mutate? The link shows similar code that does `"pipe"` in `%>%` a data.frame. This code snippet won't work in isolation without piped in data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get that error if you run those lines of code by themselves, without the data.
You need to pipe in the data like this:

```
tokens %>%
  mutate(file = "mix.data") %>% # add the name of our file
      mutate(filenumber = as.numeric(str_match(file, "\\d{4}"))) %>% # add the year
      mutate(topic = str_match(file, "(.*?)_")[2]) # add president
```